# How to fetch data from aws iot platform

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot

I want to fetch data from the AWS IoT broker.  An API is available on github and its complete documentation is available on the AWS official site for this purpose.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/aws-java-sdk-iot
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html
I could not find a single example for it in java supporting MQTT or HTTP protocol. Are there any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for trying out AWS IoT. Few parts to the answer.

First, the Java SDK is still in the works. Node, Android and iOS(Swift) are posted so far. You could reuse the Android work, but...

Second point, AWS IoT supports straight up MQTT/TLS connections so you could just use the off the shelf Paho client. Docs are [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/)

For HTTP posting, you can simply use the CLI. Hope this helps

Comment: Alright!! but can you tell if it is possible to write a client like MQTT.fx using java api?

Comment: Absolutely possible.

Comment: yes. i wrote following https://gist.github.com/sharonbn/4104301 link.
But accroding to this mqtt java api doesn't have any method to directly accept X.059 certificates for SSL connection as available in Python api. is there any more efficient way to acheive this?